# Values not updates after update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am developing a project in ASP.NET with c# and SQL Server 2005 as back end. It includes a page `profile.aspx` which displays the information of a user from database. The session variable is used  to keep track of the current logged in user.

The `profiles` table in the database contains a `username` column and 10 others columns like `dept, address, contact, skills, interests` etc etc.

I am displaying all these values on `profile.aspx`. Another page is `edit_profile.aspx` which comes up when the edit button on `profile.aspx` is clicked. Here the data is displayed in textboxes, with older entries already displayed, which can be edited, and click the `Update` button to confirm.

The update query runs fine, there is no error, but the values are not updates in the database tables. What is the possible reason? Solution?

Thank you

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CNS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@CNS);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from profiles where username='" +     Session["currentusername"].ToString()+"'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds, "profiles");
    txt_name.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][0].ToString();
    txt_deptt.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
    txt_qualificatns.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][2].ToString();
    txt_add.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][3].ToString();
    txt_contacts.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][4].ToString();
    txt_interests.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][5].ToString();
    txt_awards.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][6].ToString();
    txt_website.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][7].ToString();
    txt_skills.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][8].ToString();
    txt_mstatus.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][9].ToString();
    ds.Reset();
}



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CNS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@CNS);
    SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand("update profiles set department='"+txt_deptt.Text+"',qualifications='"+txt_qualificatns.Text+"', address='"+txt_add.Text+"', contacts='"+txt_contacts.Text+"', interests='"+txt_interests.Text+"', awards='"+txt_awards.Text+"', website='"+txt_website.Text+"', skills='"+txt_skills.Text+"', mstatus='"+txt_mstatus.Text+"' where username='" + Session["currentusername"].ToString() + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        int temp=sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (temp >= 1)
        {
            lbl_message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lbl_message.Text = "Profile Updated Successfully!";
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lbl_message.Text = "Integer less than 1";
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        lbl_message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lbl_message.Text = "Try Again Later, An Error Occured!";
    }
    //Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us what happens when you click that button (the code).

Comment: your update statement is updating the wrong records. (or no records) successfully. im possible to answer in the questions current form.

Comment: When i click that button, the page "profile.aspx" shows up! But it contains the older values with nothing updated!

Comment: @Randy: I also think so, but I have checked everything i could. Why is it not updating any values?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal Of course it shows up, but we can't say what's wrong with your code if we don't see your code.

Comment: the code is too lengthy to be posted here... what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the contents of your textboxes every time the page loads so the user inputted conntet is never written to the database...

Look at the Page.IsPostBack method. Basically, wrap the commands to fill the textboxes with

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {}
```

---

To only load the values into the text box the first time the page loads (and so not overwrite the user entered values when you click the button you need to check that the page isn't a post back.

I think maybe a book on basic ASP.Net will help answer many questions you may have early on.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    string CNS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@CNS);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from profiles where username='" +     Session["currentusername"].ToString()+"'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds, "profiles");
    txt_name.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][0].ToString();
    txt_deptt.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][1].ToString();
    txt_qualificatns.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][2].ToString();
    txt_add.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][3].ToString();
    txt_contacts.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][4].ToString();
    txt_interests.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][5].ToString();
    txt_awards.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][6].ToString();
    txt_website.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][7].ToString();
    txt_skills.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][8].ToString();
    txt_mstatus.Text = ds.Tables["profiles"].Rows[0][9].ToString();
    ds.Reset();
}
}
```

Comment: i did it and got the values updated fine. But, I wanted to load the older values in the textboxes as the page loads. These values are edited by the user and the UPDATE button does its work then. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This will load the values from the database when the page loads. When the user updates the textboxes these values will remain as the user enters them. To re-fill the values form the database once updated, simply populate them again from the database on the Button1_Click method after updating the database.